# How to get the MetadataContainerID for Tooling API for editing Visualforce Page

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

I am trying to edit an ApexPage using a ToolingAPI and containing a ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember. I have created a ToolingAPI class based on @AndyFawcett (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) the author of ToolingAPI.cls. 
I have changed the code for ApexPageMember class as suggested by another user here.

```
public class ApexPageMember extends SObject_x  implements ISerialize {
    public String            body;
    public String            content;
    public ApexPage          contentEntity;
    public String            contentEntityId;
    public DateTime          lastSyncDate;
    public Metadata          metadata;
    public MetadataContainer metadataContainer;
    public Id                metadataContainerId;
    public ApexPageMember() {
        super(SObjectType.ApexPageMember);
    }
    public override void serialize(JSONGenerator jsonGen) {
        super.serialize(jsonGen);
        if(body!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('body', body);
        if(content!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('content', content);
        if(contentEntity!=null)
            jsonGen.writeObjectField('contentEntity', contentEntity);
        if(contentEntityId!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('contentEntityId', contentEntityId);
        if(lastSyncDate!=null)
            jsonGen.writeDateTimeField('lastSyncDate', lastSyncDate);
        if(metadata!=null)
            jsonGen.writeObjectField('metadata', metadata);
        if(metadataContainer!=null)
            jsonGen.writeObjectField('metadataContainer', metadataContainer);
        if(metadataContainerId!=null)
            jsonGen.writeStringField('metadataContainerId', metadataContainerId);
    }
}
```

In order to call this class, I need three Ids, MetadataContainerId, ContentEntityId and Body. As far as I understand ContentEntityID is the ID of the Visualforce page to be updated, Body is the body of the Visualforce page.
My questions are:

1. How can I get the MetadataContainerID?
2. If I call the class like this, I should put the Body of the VF page in  apexPageMember.Body and id of the page in ContentEntityID. How to get the MetadataContainerID?

   ```
   ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember apexPageMember = new ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember(); // Create ApexPageMember and associate them with the    MetadataContainer     
   apexPageMember.Body                = fileSaveBody;
   apexPageMember.ContentEntityId     = item.id;
   apexPageMember.MetadataContainerId = containerId;      
   ToolingAPI.SaveResult apexClassMemberSaveResult =  tool.createSObject(apexPageMember);
   ```

Please explain in simple steps and in detail since I am new to Tooling API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the MetadataContainer via a separate API call. Example in Apex from [Going Native with the Apex UML Tool and Tooling API!](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/03/17/going-native-with-the-apex-uml-tool-and-tooling-api/):

```
string yourContainerName = 'ApexNavigator';

ToolingApi tooling = new ToolingApi();
List<MetadataContainer> containers = (List<MetadataContainer>)
    tooling.query(
        'SELECT Id, Name FROM MetadataContainer WHERE Name = \''+yourContainerName+'\'').records;
if(containers!=null &&  containers.size()>0) {
    tooling.deleteSObject(ToolingAPI.SObjectType.MetadataContainer, containers[0].Id);
}

// Create MetadataContainer
ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer container = new ToolingAPI.MetadataContainer();
container.name = yourContainerName;
ToolingAPI.SaveResult containerSaveResult = tooling.createSObject(container);
if(!containerSaveResult.success) {
    throw makeException(containerSaveResult);
}
Id containerId = containerSaveResult.id;
```

Then use the `containerId` for your MetadataContainerId.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.It is very helpful. I was able to generate the MetadataContainer ID with this code. However, the Visualforce page I am trying to update is not getting updated. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I am calling this class from the developer console in the following way:

Comment: The code I am using to call:                                                                   ToolingApi tool = new ToolingApi();
ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember apexPageMember = new ToolingAPI.ApexPageMember();    
apexPageMember.Body = 'abc'; //updated body
apexPageMember.ContentEntityId     = '06690000005eAf5';//id of page
apexPageMember.MetadataContainerId = '1dc90000000NRkqAAG';      //id of metadata container
ToolingAPI.SaveResult apexPageMemberSaveResult =  tool.createSObject(apexPageMember);

Comment: @SFDC_CRM What does the `apexPageMemberSaveResult` say happened?

Comment: I found out that it is necessary to have a createContainerAsyncRequest method and call it with the MetadataContainerID to finally update the page. Thank you so much for your help.